# Matplotlib not showing lines on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, pycharm

Hello I am new to Python and I was following a tutorial just to see how matplotlib draws a graph and the problem is the graph is not showing any lines. Can someone please point out where the issue is?
I am using **Python 3.7.5**
and **matplotlib 3.1.1**

this is the tutorial link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIywmJbGH-8&t=109s

the code

```
import time
import psutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.show()

i = 0
x, y = [], []

while True:
    x.append(i)
    y.append(psutil.cpu_percent())

    ax.plot(x, y, color='b')

    fig.canvas.draw()

    ax.set_xlim(left=max(0, i - 50), right=i + 50)

    time.sleep(0.1)
    i += 1

plt.close()
```

and the output I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8QAx.png)

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: The video uses a jupyter notebook. What environment do you use?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am using PyCharm

Comment: In that case you probably need to select an interactive backend; try `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`. Also you might need to replace `sleep` by `plt.pause(0.1)`.

Comment: It's working now! thank you so much @importanceofbeingernest

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, it works if executed in a Jupyter Notebook.

While one normally shows all code as text, I'm using a picture here to convey how it would look like in a notebook.

[image: e]